# setText in TextView dialog disappears

Tags: android

I have custom dialogfragment inside this i have this method.

```
private void setValue() throws ParseException {
    List<String> status = new ArrayList<String>(2);

    status.add(ClientConstants.ACCEPT.toString());
    status.add(ClientConstants.PENDING.toString());
    status.add(ClientConstants.RESOLVED.toString());


    spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(activity,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, status);
    spinnerAdapter
            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
    spinnerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    vehicleNo.setText(item.getVehicleNo());
    Date date = DDMMMYYYY.parse(item.getDueDate());
    item.setDueDate(DDMMYYY.format(date));
    dueDate.setText(item.getDueDate());

    if (item.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase(ClientConstants.OPEN.toString())) {
        spinner.setSelection(0);
        acceptTextView.setText(spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
    } else if (item.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase(
            ClientConstants.PENDING.toString())) {
        spinner.setSelection(1);
        pendingTextView.setText(spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
    } else {
        spinner.setSelection(2);
        resolvedTextView.setText(spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
    }
}
```

> acceptTextView.setText(spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());

When i click on time first its shows the textview with the selecteditem toString. as Accept.

Click back button and again viewing the dialog the setText on textview disappears.

How do i keep the textview in that dialog.

Tried to invalidate viewGroup its not working.

SOLUTION:

The try catch method seems to be a problem when calling setText.

I moved the whole things out of it except the Date.parse

Comment: When your setValue() method is being called?

Comment: setValue() called when onCreateView

Answer (score 0):

During your onPause, save the text, to the bundle.

Then, during onResume, re-writte the text.

Also, check onSaveInstanceState for additional help.